# SQL Like value from another table and wildcharcters

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables, the value of NDC_10 for table test is a 10 digit code while the value of PRODUCTNDC in table product is a 8 digit code.  I am trying to select all of the rows in which the 8 digit code is inside the 10 digit code such as:
0123456789 = 10 digits
12345678 = 8 digits

I have come up with something like this logically, but I do not know how to nest the 2 wild characters inside the search of the other table

```
select NDC_10
FROM test, product
WHERE (NDC_10 LIKE '_product.PRODUCTNDC_')
```

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you're asking, but perhaps you mean to do a JOIN?

Comment: I need to join only when the 8 digit code from product.PRODUCTNDC is inside the NDC_10 from digit surrounded by a character in front and one behing (giving you 10 digits instead of 8, so only join when the 8 digit code is nested inside of the 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t.NDC_10, p.NDC_8
FROM test t
INNER JOIN product p ON (LOCATE(p.NDC_8,t.NDC_10) <> 0)
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate
And: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

And never ever use implicit join syntax, it is an antipattern.
The reason is that it's too easy to do a cross join which in 99,99% of all cases is not what you want.

Comment: Still going slow, but I assume that has more to do with the fact I am checking 80k rows to 260k rows.  Thanks for the help + resources.

Answer (score -1):

The wildcard character for LIKE searches is `%`. So if I wanted to get all records that contained your 8 digit code, I would do this:

```
SELECT NDC_10
FROM test, product
WHERE NDC_10 LIKE '%12345678%'
```

If I only want ones that *start* with the 8 digit code, then this will work:

```
SELECT NDC_10
FROM test, product
WHERE NDC_10 LIKE '12345678%'
```

And if I only want records that *end* with the same 8 digits:

```
SELECT NDC_10
FROM test, product
WHERE NDC_10 LIKE '%12345678'
```

Hope that answers your question.

If you're trying to do it across a join, then try this:

```
SELECT test.NDC_10
FROM test
    INNER JOIN product ON test.NDC_10 LIKE '%' + product.PRODUCTNDC + '%'
```

Comment: I would have guess the '%' + product.PRODUCTNDC + '%' is correct, but it just gives me a 1064 syntax error.

Comment: Looks like     select NDC_10
FROM  testt, product
WHERE NDC_10 LIKE   CONCAT('%', product.PRODUCTNDC, '%')  does the trick, thanks for the help

Comment: -1 For using an implicit join. Because you did not specify a join criterion you have done a cross join. This will be much much slower than needed. And besides, implicit joins are an anti-pattern all by themselves.

Comment: Then whats a better suggestion?

Comment: @chrstahl89, Use an explicit join and declare a join condition, this will drastically reduce the number of rows under consideration, speeding up your query. Right now if both tables have a 1,000 rows, MySQL will generate (1,000 x 1,000 = 1 million rows) in a temp table and do the `like` search on that.

Comment: You're right Jordan, was just following the OPs conditions. Will edit appropriately.